# Continue asking for input, for a given try, if input is illegal

Tags: python

If the user does not put a numerical value, how can I make them continue attempting for them to put a number for a particular try? For example, if they do not put in a number for try 2, is it possible for them to continue inputing a value for this try?

```
correct_number = 7

for x in range(1, 4):
    try:  
        user_guess = int(input('Attempt ' + str(x) + ': '))
    except ValueError:
        print('You did not enter a numerical value for year.')
        break
    
    if user_guess == 7:
        print('Good job!')
        break
```

Comment: don't `break` if they're wrong

Answer (score 0):

We add a flag `is_number_given` that is initialized to False.

When we get value from the user, either:

1. It's not a number, an exception is raised, `is_number_given` flag remains False, so we keep asking for a value
2. The value given is a number, we set `is_number_given` flag to True and end this try session

```
correct_number = 7

for x in range(1, 4):
    user_guess = None
    is_number_given = False
    while not is_number_given:
        try:
            user_guess = int(input('Attempt ' + str(x) + ': '))
            is_number_given = True
        except ValueError:
            print('You did not enter a numerical value for year.')

    # Better use `user_guess == correct_number`
    # so there is one place in code where `correct_number` value exists
    if user_guess == 7:
        print('Good job!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use while loop and then use the`continue`to Return attempt try this code its work:enter code here:[its work perfectly:click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp8Zo.png)